# How do you find what angle you would have to turn to be facing an object at a certain point

Tags: geometry

Lets say a 2D object is at point (2, 3).  There is an object at point (5, 1).  In relation to the object at (2, 3), what angle is the object at (5, 1)?  Another way to ask the question would be, if the object at (2, 3) was facing 0 radians, how many radians would it have to turn to be facing the object, (and not turn the longest way possible to be facing it)?  The answer would be positive I think, but how would you find it?

Edit:
I am trying to find what angle an object would have to face to be facing the center of a group of objects, so it doesn't matter what direction it is facing initially.  Also the points above are just examples, a generic algorithm is needed.  Hopefully this clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

(Edited following @pjs36's comment, which made me re-read the question and realize I was answering something that wasn't asked.)

Assuming you mean "using a computer, how would you find it?", one answer is

```
a = atan2(1-3, 5-2)
b = atan2(3, 2)
angle = b - a
```

That says (1) find the angle from the $x$-axis to the direction of the ray through $P$ in Narasimhan's answer, and (2) move $P$ to the origin, hence $Q$ to $(5-2, 3-1)$, and find the angle from the $x$ axis to the line through this translated point.

There's still a problem if the angle is large, so here's a superior answer.

```
let dot(u, v, a, b) = u*a + v*b
px = 2
py = 3
qx = 5
qy = 1

dx = qx - px
dy = qy - py
// d represents how much you have to move in x and y to get from
// P to Q

r = sqrt ( dot(px, py, px, py) ) // distance from P to origin. 
vx = px/r
vy = py/r

c = dot(dx, dy, vx, vy)
s = dot(dx, dy, -vy, vx)
angle = atan2(s, c)
```

The only problem here occurs if P is the origin; in that case, r = 0 and the division fails. But if $P$ is the origin, the "direction to P" is undefined, so the code *should* fail.

N.B. You can get away with just letting $vx = px; vy = py$ and forgetting the division by $r$, because $atan2$ doesn't care about constant multiples. But for those who know some linear algebra, normalizing the vector $v$, so that $v$ and $v^\perp$ form an *orthonormal* basis, has a kind of natural feel to it.

Note that what I've written above will work for any $P$ and $Q$ (except $P = (0,0)$)-- you can replace them in lines 2-5 of the code.

Comment: Could we fix this by (mentally) sliding the reference object to the origin, as in `atan2(1 - 3, 5 - 2)`?

Comment: Thanks very much; I've rewritten my answer based on your far better reading of the question!

Comment: Actually I had a hard time reading the question; I was mostly just going off of your answer, hoping there was a better way to avoid ambiguity! :)

Comment: This answer would also work but I can only accept one.  Also sorry for the ambiguity of the question, I'm making a flocking algorithm and need to know some very specific things.  I will clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

I call the points P and Q. You want to find difference of rotation $ = \psi $

$$ \theta1 = \tan^{-1} \frac {y1}{x1} , \quad  OP = \sqrt{ x1^2 +y1^2} $$

$$ \theta2 = \tan^{-1} \frac {y2}{x2} , \quad  OQ = \sqrt{ x2^2 +y2^2} $$

$$ PQ^2 = (x2-x1)^2 + (y2-y1)^2 $$

$$ \dfrac{\sin \psi}{ OQ } =\dfrac{\sin (\theta_2 - \theta_1)}{ PQ } $$

Since there are two possibilities you need to choose one from obtuse or acute angles $\psi.$

If a continuous curve between P,Q is drawn, $ \psi$ is secant rotation.

[image: Rotation]

Comment: Hehe I'm taking algebra 2 right now, but i'll try to understand that.

Comment: No trig, no angle!

Comment: I'm confused on why theta2 is atany2/x2, wheres the right triangle?

Comment: It is polar angle argument for Q , y2= q ; shall load the coordinate line also.. the right angle at $q$ had to be imagined earlier.

Comment: I just realized that I only need to know the angle in relation to the first point but this answers the original question.